# Should we advertise this site while it's in private beta?

Tags: discussion

This site was advertised on Math Stack Exchange, Math Overflow, and a few of the math subreddits while it was in the Definition phase, and again during the Commitment phase.

Would it make sense to advertise the site again now that it's in Beta, or should we wait until the Beta is public?

Comment: I believe that we should wait until the public beta. People only mildly interested might be turned off by a barebones site.

Comment: I think it might be good to reach out strategically to constituencies that are part of at least some users' articulated ideal vision for the site but are as yet underrepresented. I'm thinking in specific of K-12 educators and academic researchers in education.

Comment: I think it would behoove us to think of particular demographics that are *underrepresented* currently and actively reach out to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that this site is staying longer than a week in private beta, now might be a good time to invite other people in, especially from underrepresented demographics, as brendansullivan07 says. The site is just as well established, if not better, than other sites that have made public beta.

Comment: Is it known that we're staying notably longer than a week, or is this just observation on when we started?

Comment: A Stackexchange employee said in chat that public beta will probably begin next week. (chat is available to see under the Stackexchange menu in the upper left corner).